# How to disable autocompletetextview changing its text?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

The problem that I'm facing is: that I need to disable the callback that's being made when I click on a dropdown item. When I click on the item it changes the text in the autocompletextview and I don't need this functionality. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 5):

Solved this problem by overriding the the `AutoCompleteTextView` class and overriding `replaceText` function.